# Debugging ECX_BAD_ACCESS error C++

Tags: c++, exception

Any ideas how to fix the following error with the following code? This is in a C++ environment in Xcode.

```
    //
//  main.cpp
//  Chess
//
//  Created by Akshar Ramkumar on 9/29/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Akshar Ramkumar. All rights reserved.
//

#include "Declarations.hpp"
#include "DeclarationsMain.hpp"
extern simplePiece TotalBoard[8][8];
using namespace std;
int main() {




    Piece All[32];
    start(All);
    char rawinput[4];
    char fxinput;
    char fyinput;
    char txinput;
    char tyinput;
    while(true){
        Turn=not Turn;
        if(Turn==true){
            TurnColor="white";

        }


        else {

            TurnColor="black";

        }

        cout<<"It is "<<TurnColor<<"'s turn"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter the x and y coordinates you want to move from 0-7, 0-7 (no spaces in between)"<<endl;
        cin>>rawinput;
        fxinput=rawinput[0];
        fyinput=rawinput[2];
        cout<<"Enter the x and y coordinates you want to move to 0-7, 0-7 "<<endl;
        cin>>rawinput;
        txinput=rawinput[0];
        tyinput=rawinput[2];
        if(TotalBoard[fxinput][fyinput].Color==Turn and TotalBoard[fxinput][fyinput].Color==true){

            TotalBoard[txinput][tyinput]=TotalBoard[fxinput][fyinput];
            TotalBoard[fxinput][fyinput].Color=false;
            TotalBoard[fxinput][fyinput].Type=0;
            TotalBoard[fxinput][fyinput].exists=false;






        }



    }


    return 0;
}
```

Next:

```
//
//  Classes.cpp
//  Chess
//
//  Created by Akshar Ramkumar on 10/13/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Akshar Ramkumar. All rights reserved.
//Pawn = 0
//Rook = 1
//Knight = 2
//Bishop = 3
//King = 4
//Queen = 5

#include "Declarations.hpp"
#include "DeclarationsBoard.hpp"
void start(Piece All[32]){
    int TypeArray[32];
    int xValues[32];
    int yValues[32];
    std::ifstream startstate;
    std::fstream boardstate;
    std::string numread;
    char delim=' ';
    startstate.open("/Users/aksramk/Google Drive/For Fun/Programming/Pascal C++/Chess/boardstatestart.txt")
    ;
    boardstate.open("/Users/aksramk/Google Drive/For Fun/Programming/Pascal C++/Chess/boardstatecurrent.txt");
    for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
        getline(startstate, numread,delim);


        TypeArray[i]=atoi(numread.c_str());

    }

    for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
        getline(startstate, numread, delim);


        xValues[i]=atoi(numread.c_str());
    }

    for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
        getline(startstate, numread, delim);


        yValues[i]=atoi(numread.c_str());

    }


    for (int i=0;i<32;i++){


        All[i].Type = TypeArray[i];
        All[i].y = yValues[i];
        All[i].x = xValues[i];
        All[i].Color = true;
        All[i].Captured = false;


        if (i>15){
            All[i].Color = false;
        }
    }
    startstate.close();
    for(int i=0;i<32;i++){

        boardstate<<TypeArray[i];
        boardstate<<" ";

    }
    for(int i=0;i<32;i++){

        boardstate<<xValues[i];
        boardstate<<" ";

    }
    for(int i=0;i<32;i++){

        boardstate<<yValues[i];
        boardstate<<" ";

    }

    for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
        boardstate<<0;
        boardstate<<" ";

    }
    boardstate.close();
    ;

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
            simplePiece temp;

            for(int k=0;k<32;k++){
                Piece temp2=All[k];
                if(temp2.x==i and temp2.y==j){

                    temp.Type=temp2.Type;
                    temp.Color=temp2.Color;
                    temp.exists=true;
                }

            }
            TotalBoard[i][j]=temp;

        }
    }


    };
```

Headers:

```
//  DeclarationsMain.h
//  Chess
//
//  Created by Akshar Ramkumar on 11/22/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Akshar Ramkumar. All rights reserved.
//

#ifndef DeclarationsMain_h
#define DeclarationsMain_h
bool Turn=false;
std::string TurnColor;

#endif /* DeclarationsMain_h */
```

Next:

```
  //
//  DeclarationsBoard.h
//  Chess
//
//  Created by Akshar Ramkumar on 11/22/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Akshar Ramkumar. All rights reserved.
//

#ifndef board
#define board
simplePiece TotalBoard[8][8];

#endif
```

Next:

```
//
//  DataStructures.hpp
//  Chess
//
//  Created by Akshar Ramkumar on 10/18/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Akshar Ramkumar. All rights reserved.
//


#ifndef iostream
#define iostream
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


#endif

#ifndef piece
#define piece
class Piece {
    public:
        int Type;
        int x;
        int y;
        bool Captured;
        bool Color;


};

struct simplePiece{
    bool Color=false;
    int Type=0;
    bool exists=false;


};
void start(Piece All[32]);
#endif
```

The line :

```
TotalBoard[txinput][tyinput]=TotalBoard[fxinput][fyinput];
```

throws the error: "Thread 1: ECX_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x100009bac).

Does anyone have any ideas about how to fix this?

Thanks so much, and sorry for the simple question (I am a beginner).

Comment: If you use a debugger to step through your code one line at a time, and examine what the values of fxinput, fyinput, txinput, and tyinput are, after changing their types to `int`, I am fairly certain that you will figure out your own bug, all by yourself. Free clue: when you type in the coordinates 0 through 7, to be entered into those variables, the actual values of those variables will ***not*** be 0 through 7.

Comment: I have tried this. TotalBoard does not seem to exist in the scope of main.cpp.

Comment: What does that have anything to do with the values of those four variables, in main.cpp? Did you read my comment, or someone else's?

Comment: I read your comment. The variable TotalBoard did not exist, while all the other variables that should have did.

Comment: Where in my comment did I mention anything about TotalBoard?

Comment: It does not have to do with TotalBoard.

Comment: The issue is not that fxinput, fyinput, txinput, and tyinput are incorrect values. TotalBoard does not even seem to be in the scope when you look at it through the debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relevant parts from your code:

```
char rawinput[4];

cin>>rawinput;
fxinput=rawinput[0];
fyinput=rawinput[2];
```

The input operation here reads a "word" (essentially text without spaces) into that character array. Let's say the user inputs "1 2". The first word here is "1". The `rawinput` array then holds a C string consisting of the ASCII value for "1", followed by a nullbyte.

`rawinput[0]` is then 49.

`rawinput[2]` is then some indeterminate value, whatever was there before.

---

One solution is to use `int` variables:

```
int x;
int y;

cin >> x >> y;
```

Comment: How should we fix this?

Comment: You should fix this by reading your C++ book, which explains what needs to be fixed.

Comment: TotalBoard does not seem to exist in the main scope